# PhotoSwipe multiple galleries on one site

Tags: jquery, typo3, photoswipe

I use PhotoSwipe on Typo3 based homepage using the yag-gallery extension and PhotoSwipe. I have 5 galleries on one site. When I click an image in one of the galleries, only the images of the last gallery are shown.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row col span_12">
    <div class="headlines">
        <div class="tx-yag-pi1 theme-photoswipe">
        <div id="yag-c84" class="yag-list-wrap yag-gallery">
            <ul>
                <div class="tx-yag-items gallery-row">
                    <li id="yag_2" class="tx-yag-thumb-outerframe yag-item-thumb-outerframe gallery-item">
                        <div class="tx-yag-thumb-innerframe yag-item-thumb-innerframe">
                            <a class="gallery-link" href="typo3temp/yag/02/test1.jpg">
                                <img class="gallery-img" width="150px" height="150px" src="typo3temp/yag/00/test1.jpg" title="test" alt="test">
                             </a>
                         </div>
                     </li>
                     <li id="yag_3" class="tx-yag-thumb-outerframe yag-item-thumb-outerframe gallery-item">
                     <li id="yag_4" class="tx-yag-thumb-outerframe yag-item-thumb-outerframe gallery-item">
                     <li id="yag_5" class="tx-yag-thumb-outerframe yag-item-thumb-outerframe gallery-item">
                     <li id="yag_6" class="tx-yag-thumb-outerframe yag-item-thumb-outerframe gallery-item">
                 </div>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row col span_12">
<div class="row col span_12">
<div class="row col span_12">
<div class="row col span_12">
```

This is the jQuery to call PhotoSwipe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myGallery = $(".yag-gallery").each(function(){
        $(this).find("a").photoSwipe();
    });
});
```

Has anyone got any idea how I can call each gallery individually?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512946/configure-photoswipe-to-not-use-entire-window#65875907) of how I solved multiple galleries on one page. I basically got it to work by getting a PhotoSwipe page working then embedding it multiple times using `object`.