# Configure PhotoSwipe to Not Use Entire Window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I'm currently trying to build a mobile image gallery using [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/).
I've been able to get it working but there's one small problem.  When I
click on a photo thumbnail, the actual photo always takes up the entire
viewport.  This is OK when you're viewing the gallery on a mobile device.
But if your viewport is a computer screen and the image isn't a 
high-res one, the photo can be very blurry.  I'd rather limit the photo
to a width of maybe 300 to 400 pixels when viewed on a computer.  Is there
a way to do this in PhotoSwipe?  I read the documentation but couldn't
quite figure it out.  I've enclosed my code below.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PhotoSwipe - jQuery Mobile Version</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/photoswipe/photoswipe.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mediaqueries.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        div.gallery-row:after {
            clear: both;
            content: ".";
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        div.gallery-item {
            float: left;
            width: 33.333333%;
        }
        div.gallery-item a {
            display: block;
            margin: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
        }
        div.gallery-item img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        #Gallery1 .ui-content, #Gallery2 .ui-content {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/simple-inheritance.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/photoswipe/code-photoswipe-jQuery-1.0.11.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div.gallery-page').live('pageshow', function(e) {
                // Re-initialize with photos for the current page
                $('div.gallery a', e.target).photoSwipe();
                return true;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="Home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>PhotoSwipe</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" >  
            <p>These examples show PhotoSwipe integrated with jQuery Mobile:</p>        
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#Gallery1">First Gallery</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#Gallery2">Second Gallery</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&copy; 2011 PhotoSwipe</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="Gallery1" class="gallery-page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>First Gallery</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <div class="gallery">
                <div class="gallery-row">
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/01.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/01-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 1" /></a></div>
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/02.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/02-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 2" /></a></div>
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/03.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/03-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 3" /></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-row">
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/04.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/04-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 4" /></a></div>
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/05.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/05-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 5" /></a></div>
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/06.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/06-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 6" /></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-row">
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/07.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/07-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 7" /></a></div>
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/08.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/08-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 8" /></a></div>
                    <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/09.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/09-thumb.jpg" alt="Image 9" /></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&copy; 2011 PhotoSwipe</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put **Photoswipe** markup (root element with class `pswp`) to any container with `position: relative` and edit *photoswipe.css* or add to your stylesheet something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photoswipe in container</title>
    <style>
        #myContainer {
            position: relative;

            /* other container styles */
        }

        .pswp {
            position: absolute!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myContainer">
        <!-- Root element of PhotoSwipe. Must have class pswp. -->
        <div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <!-- standard markup omitted -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

PhotoSwipe has a `modal` option:

```
var options = {
    modal: false
}
var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( someElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, someItems, options);
gallery.init();
```

which makes the PhotoSwipe container take only the size of its parent when set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of an automatic way to do this, what i did was to put the .pswp div inside of a container div with fixed width and height and then position that container div via JS + CSS in the center of the screen.
Use a basic setup as described on the photoswipe documentation with the pswp div already added and then:

HTML

```
<div id="pswp-container">
  <div class="pswp">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pswp-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;    
}
.pswp {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

JS

```
// Centers the Photoswipe container in the center of the screen (call on init + resize)
function centerPhotoswipe() {
    var ww = $(window).innerWidth();
    var wh = $(window).innerHeight();
    var $el = $("#pswp-container");
    var w = $el.outerWidth();
    var h = $el.outerHeight();

    $el.css({
        left:   Math.round( (ww-w) / 2),
        top:    Math.round( (wh-h) / 2)
    });
}
```

You can find a working example [here at CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogZdgp).

This should give you the desired effect and a good starting point for your own page, BUT keep in mind that it will be necessary to add your own background layer to trigger the 'close on click somewhere else' and other details that you have to fix during the opening / closing events of the popup ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried all sorts of solutions to get this to work properly, including the [inline gallery](https://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#inline-gallery) options ([demo](https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/JogxWM)).

However I couldn't quite get it to work as I wanted as I needed the a specific gallery to display without showing the thumbnails first.

What I did in the end was get a basic PhotoSwipe page working which automatically loaded the images on page load to a full screen, for example using an MVC URL:

- `/Gallery/Index/1`

then simply embed this link in a `div` [using `object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements):

```
<div id="mygallery1">
    <object data="/Gallery/Index1">
        Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
    </object>
</div>
```

This allowed me to place as many galleries as I wanted in whatever position I wanted without any interference between them.

Note though that this didn't seem to work for mobile browsers, which was fine as for screens that small I wanted a fallback option anyway to render as an overlay over the whole page due to limited screen real estate.